# Problems sending notify email on Mturk using boto in live instance

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, boto, mechanicalturk

Has anyone faced problems with sending email notification to Mturk users in the live instance, while using boto?
Here is my code, which works perfectly fine in the Sandbox version.
I tested with my own Mturk workerID and I do get an email when it is Sandbox, but this does not work for live. Neither does it throw any error.

```
site = "live"
mtc = connect_mturk(site)   
workerids = ['Axxxxxx']
msg = "Hits for you"
subject = "Hello"
for id in workerids:
    mtc.notify_workers(id, subject, msg)
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found the solution. Read in the [AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=100140) that,

The NotifyWorkers API call will only send email to a worker who has ever submitted results for a HIT you created that you have approved or rejected.  If you submit a NotifyWorkers request to a WorkerId that doesn't match that criteria, no email will be sent.

I was using my own worker ID to test and since I had not worked on any hits of my own hits in the live instance, the API was not sending me any email. Phew can't believe I spend so much time racking my brains on this.